# Python(sympy) : How to graph smoothly in 2nd ODE solution with Sympy?

Tags: python, sympy, graphing

I'm studing about structural dynamic analysis.
I solved a problem : 1 degree of freedom

**The question is
m*y'' + cy' + ky = 900 sin(5.3x)
m=6938.78, c=5129.907, k=379259, y is the function of x**

I solved it's response using by Python and Sympy library.
I drew the response by pyplot. But it's shape is not smooth like below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSXZK.png)

How can I draw the respone smoothly?

I tried to draw smoothly by substituting each x to y by numpy, but could not insert x into sin(5.3x).

```
from sympy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y=symbols("x, y")
f=symbols('f',cls=Function)
y=f(x)

eq=Eq( 6938.78*diff(y,x,2)  +  5129.907*diff(y,x) + 379259*y-900*sin(5.3*x),0)

eq_done=dsolve(eq,y, ics={  f(0):0,  diff(y,x).subs(x,0):0   }  )

plot(eq_done.rhs,(x,0,10))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a smoother line you can turn off the adaptive algorithm and set the number of points per line:

```py
plot(eq_done.rhs,(x,0,10), adaptive=False, nb_of_points=1000)
```

Also, the `help()` function is your friend, as it allows to quickly access the documentation of a particular function. Execute `help(plot)` to learn more about the `plot` command.